# How to navigate Web Pages in Perl using WWW::Mechanize and dropdowns?

Tags: perl

I am having a problem, what i am trying to do is:

I open a webpage with WWW::Mechanize, fill the username and password and log in.

The issue I am having is, after logging in I have to select the value from a dropdown list
and after that I have to press submit.

How can i do that?

The code which i have used is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
use  WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use strict;

my $username="123456";
my $password="XXXXX";
my $project="Systems";
my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$agent->get('http://www.XXXXX.com');
$agent->form_name("login_form");
$agent->field("txtLoginId", $username);
$agent->field("txtPassword", $password);
$agent->submit();
#Till now it has success full logined, From here it has to select one value from a drop #down box
$agent->form_name("frmProject");
$agent->field("cboProject", $project);
my $response=$agent->submit();

if ($response->is_success){
  print "\nContent:\n";
  print $response->as_string;
}elsif ($response->is_error){
  print $response->error_as_HTML;
}
```

Comment: You should *always* `use warnings` as well as `use strict` to get the maximum amount of help from perl

Answer (score 2):

WWW::Mechanize has a `click` method that you can use to click on a button. Or, study the `submit_form` method for which you can specify values of all the form elements. If the page uses javascript, WWW:Mechanize might be not suitable for your task (see for example [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) for an alternative).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`select` method](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#mech-select-name-value-). If you know the value (not the display-text), use this:

```
$agent->form_name("frmProject");
$agent->select('cboProject', $project);
my $response = $agent->submit();
```

If you don't take a look at the [Mechanize FAQ](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFAQ#How-do-I-pick-a-specific-value-from-a-list-). It says you have to do something like this:

```
# Find the correct input element
my ($projectlist) = $agent->find_all_inputs( name => 'cboProject' );
# Look up the value of the option

my %name_lookup;
@name_lookup{ $projectlist->value_names } = $projectlist->possible_values;

# use the display-text to get the correct value
my $value = $name_lookup{ $project };
```

---

Once you've done that, you can use the [`click`-method](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#mech-click-button-x-y-) to submit the page.

```
$agent->click_button('name_of_the_submit_button');
```

But if the button you have to click is the default action, `$agent->submit()` should do the trick as well.